# How to improve minimaztion results in scipy for this function?

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose I have a function that looks more or less like this:

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

a = 10e3
b = 10e3
c = 10e3

def f(X):
    x1,x2,x3,x4=X
    return  x1**2 + x2**2 + np.exp(x1+x3)*(a*x2**2 + b*x4**2) + c*x2 + x3 +x4 - np.log(x3)-np.log(x4)
```

(I.e. we have some very large quadratic/exponential terms and some logarithms that are not scaled in the same way)
Now I want to minimize this function using scipy.optimize.minimize.
By using Nelder-Mead, I get

```
x = optimize.minimize(f,x0=[0,0,1,1],tol=1e-64)["x"]
x
>>> array([ 1.32024622, -0.07513601,  0.04733802,  0.00612603])
```

But, I get:

```
f(x)
>>>  -518.3079632694506
```

and

```
f([x[0],x[1],1e-3,1e-3])
>>> -524.1610213067089
```

so x is not a minimum yet. I suspect this is because the true minimum of the function would lie
close to 0, where the function is undefined, such that it is difficult to reach this minimum, especially due to the scaling constants.

My question is now, how could one improve this result? Could I reparameterize the function in some way?

I already tried to use gradient-based methods, but this lead to worse solutions than this one.

---

Version info for reproducibility:

Python - 3.6.10

numpy  - 1.18.1

scipy  - 1.4.1

Comment: when I run: `f([x[0],x[1],1e-3,1e-3])` an error occured: `overflow encountered in exp`

Comment: I ran the code again and got the same results as above, and no error. I included version info above, maybe there's a difference?

Comment: Ok, now is no error in above. But when running optimization then a lot of errors displays: `__main__:3: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log`. Also optimal solution is different when different `x0` argument is provided. I've tried also another optimizers by providing `method` argument. Maybe formula is to complex and has points of discontinuity?

Comment: `f([-25, -100, 0.001, 1])` is even smaller for me. `f([-22.460008595134266, -4999.994665583297, 0.021752223937541587, 0.994193529465281])` too, but the parameters might be out of bounds. Do they need to be in a certain range?

Comment: @ipj I suppose the function does not have discontinuities (but goes to minus infinity at 0), but I guess the parameterization is maybe not optimal for the minimization methods (i.e. a small step in the x1,x2 directions changes the value a lot more than a small step in the x3,x4 directions)

Comment: @GokberkYaltirakli  These values are admitted, the only restriction here is that x3,x4 >0 since the logarithm will become undefined elsewhere.

Comment: So maybe use `x3,x4 >0` as parameter to constrained optimization.